# Entity Framework: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

before i go on, i have read all the topics by the same name and couldn't get my problem solved so i have to ask it again.

i have models like this :

```
class a {
    int id;
    class b b;
    list of class c c;
    string status 
}
class b {
    int id; //some other stuff
}
class c {
    int id; //some other stuff
}
```

so what am i trying to do is to load object of class a from database (filtered by id (pk))
then update string status (leaving related entities unchanged)
and save to database.
after changing some string fields of class a
and calling context.savechanges()
what i get as a result is duplicated row at database (of class a) with correct values but different id.
so i figured out i need to tell ef that entry's status has changed to "EntityState.Modified"
after doing so i get exception in title of the question.

**this is important**  i checked in debug mode instance of class c indeed has value of primary key before attempting to save and db indeed has row with the same pk value so i'm not trying to update nonexistent row

```
context.orders.Add(current);
                context.Entry(current).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
```

this code throws exception in title
object "current" has it's pk value in place before saving

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the first line to `Add`, and in fact will not be able to add it, because it already has a primary key. You just need to mark it as modified, then save changes.

Comment: i just tested it out, u were right. i feel so ashamed of myself right now, what a simple mistake. anyways thank you good sir

Comment: i can't mark ur comment as answer so if u'll post it as answer i'll mark it (thanks again)

Comment: @giorgi Are you sure that this entity is attached ? Are the properties public and virtual or change track is enabled? This is common when you entity is not attached or you are ignoring the primary key.

Comment: in this case loading/updating is done by same context so it's aware of object's state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity already exists in the database, so you don't need to call `Add`. This is what is causing it to fail - it already exists, and so can't be inserted again (that would break the primary key constraint). Simply marking it as modified, and saving changes, will be enough to update it in the database:

```
context.Entry(current).State = EntityState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();
```